# BlackBerry JRE independent java coding

Tags: blackberry, java

How can i develop BlackBerry JRE independent java code for an application. Here we have so many types of JREs for blackberry so i would like to run my code in all versions without having code modifications. For example, in iphone we use preprocessor statements to avoid versioning problem like that do we have any alternatives?

Thanks
venu

Answer (score 1):

There is a preprocessor for BB as well. See [the docs](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21065/Specifying_preprocessor_directives_657636_11.jsp) for how to use it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am at middle, do you have any sample codes regarding this? Otherwise tell me some reference URLs.

Comment: I thought I had provided a link. [Here it is again](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Specifying_preprocessor_directives_657636_11.jsp). The rules are fairly simple: the first line of any file to be preprocessed must be `//#preprocess`. The only preprocessing directives are `//#ifdef DIRECTIVE`...`//#else`...`//#endif` and `//#ifndef`...`//#else`...`//#endif`. You specify directives for the project in BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml or for the workspace under Window->Preferences->BlackBerry Java Plug-in->Preprocessor Directives